# Gumbel distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution

I have a silly question:
If **X** has a Gumbel distribution with parameters **mu** (location) and **beta**>0 (scale)
Then what would be the distribution of **A.X**,
where A is constant.

thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your question is better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and a google search would give you the answer. That being said, if `X` is Gumbel distributed than `a*X` would be Gumbel distributed as well (`a` is constant, lower case is used to avoid ambiguity). Using that `E[a*X] = a*E[X]` and `Var[a*X] = a^2*Var[X]`, where `E[]` and `Var[]` are the mean and variance, respectively.
Then using the formulas which express the connection between mean, variance and distribution parameters (`mu, beta`), e.g. from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Properties), one can show that `a*X` has the following parameters (denoted by underscore):

`mu_ = A*mu` and `beta_ = A*beta`

`a*X ~ Gum(mi_, beta_)`